# $E=\left\{x:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{R}: \frac{|x(n)|}{\sqrt{n}}\text{ bounded } \forall n\in\mathbb{N}\right\}$ is not complete.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $E=\left\{x:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{R}: \frac{|x(n)|}{\sqrt{n}}\text{ bounded }\forall n\in\mathbb{N}\right\}$ with metric $d(x,y)=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{|x(i)-y(i)|}{i^2}$\.

a) Let $B=\left\{\sqrt{i}e_i\right\}_{i=1}^\infty$ (with $e_i=(0,0,\ldots, 1,0,0,\ldots )$ i-position) Is $B$ totally bounded?

b) Show that $E$ is not complete.

I have the next:
(a)  $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}=(\sqrt{n}e_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is Cauchy, because if $n\not=m$, $d(x_n,x_m)=\frac{\sqrt{n}}{n^2}+\frac{\sqrt{m}}{m^2}<\epsilon$ with $n,m$ large enough. Therefore $B$ is Cauchy, then $B$ is totally bounded.

For (b), $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is Cauchy, but $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is not convergent, then $B$ is not complete.
It's correct?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: (b) Your statement is correct. The question remains: can you find a Cauchy sequence which does not converge?

Comment: @AlexG. He uses the sequence from part $(a)$ here

Comment: I may be the only one confused here, but the sequence in part $a)$ doesn't appear to be able to be used for part $b)$. I'm guessing $e_i$ represents a basis vector in $\mathbb{R}^m$ for some $m$ so that would make $\sqrt{i}e_i$ be defined with values in $\mathbb{R}^m$. You're then using the metric defined for two sequences on a single sequence it seems. In general I'm a bit confused by this (possibly others). Do you mind looking over what you typed out?

Comment: @DanZimm I think your second comment is correct. The sequence in part a) converges to the zero vector in the given metric: $$d(\sqrt{n}\,e_n, 0) = n^{-3/2}.$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint for b:** Consider $\{r_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ defined by 
$$r_n = \sum_{k=1}^n k^{p} e_k$$
where $1/2 < p < 1$.

Comment: $r_n(i)=i^p$? or not?

Comment: @user136951 $r_n(i) = i^p$ if $i \leq n$, otherwise $r_n(i) = 0$ when $i > n$.